# MS Access Call/Application.Run Procedure stored as variable not working

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I have a MS Access form with a listbox with list of procedures. The procedure codes are stored in the form. There's also a button. When clicking a button, I want it to loop through the listbox and run the procedures from the selected items. I'm calling the procedures using Call and Application.Run but both methods are giving errors.

Call 'Compile Error: Expected Sub, Function, or Proeprty
Application.Run 'MS Access cannot find the procedure 'Name of Procedure'

```
Private Sub button_Click()

With Me.listbox1
    For Each varItem In .ItemsSelected
        currSub = .ItemData(varItem)
        If Not IsNull(varItem) Then
            Call currSub 'Compile Error: Expected Sub, Function, or Proeprty                
            Application.Run currSub 'MS Access cannot find the procedure 'Name of Procedure'
        End If
    Next
End With

Sub NameOfcurrSub1()
   'some code
End Sub

Sub NameOfcurrSub2()
   'some code
End Sub
etc.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call a sub using `Application.Run`, you need to store it in a separate, *standard module* (.bas, not .cls). Move your subs to a separate module, and it will work.

The `Call` keyword is deprecated, and doesn't call a function based on a string.

Answer (score 2):

A form is a *class module*, its running instance is an *object*: `Application.Run` doesn't work off objects. If you want to invoke an object's methods, you need to use `CallByName` and specify the object instance, which would be `Me`... except you specifically can't pass `Me` directly to `CallByName`, so you could introduce a local variable to proxy the call:

```
Dim localMe As Object
Set localMe = Me
CallByName localMe, currSub, vbMethod ', arguments would go here
```

Or, move the procedures you want to invoke to a separate, *standard module*, as in [Erik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47422890/1188513).

`Call DoSomething` is 100% identical to `DoSomething`: the former is the deprecated *explicit call syntax*, the latter is the more commonly used *implicit call syntax*. Both are compile-time validated, which means doing `Call NonExistingProcedure` will throw a compile error just like invoking `NonExistingProcedure` would.